# Count array object types in one iteration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a JSON with format

```
{body => ["type"=>"user"...], ["type"=>"admin"...]}
```

I want to count the objects by type, but I don't want to iterate the array three times (that's how many different objects I have), so this won't work:

```
  @user_count = json["body"].count{|a| a['type'] == "user"}
  @admin_count = json["body"].count{|a| a['type'] == "admin"}
  ...
```

Is there a smart way to count the object types without doing an `.each` block and using if statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to create a hash with `type => count` pairs:

```
json['body'].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |a, h| h[a['type']] += 1 }
#=> {"user"=>5, "admin"=>7, ...}
```

Comment: @nesiseka regarding your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31242904/2): please edit your question accordingly if `a.type` doesn't work.

Comment: sorry for that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can store counts into a hash using one `each`:

```
counts = { "user" => 0, "admin" => 0, "whatever" => 0 }
json["body"].each do |a|
  counts[a.type] += 1
end

counts["user"] #=> 1
counts["admin"] #=> 2
counts["whatever"] #=> 3
```